# Compare row values in Pandas Dataframe over using time delta

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare row data over time intervals rather than row iterations. i.e. I want to compare a value with it's comparable value from 'X' mins ago.

Each row in my dataframe is not a standardized time increment.

Specifically, I would like to compare the `heading` value in this subset dataframe with the one 2 mins ago for example.

I have tried a few methods such as timedeltas, and .shift() method, but so far no joy and I'm confusing myself. Any thoughts, or help would be appreciated.

```
index                heading               times
2015-12-09 03:00:01      NaN 2015-12-09 03:00:01
2015-12-09 03:01:07   231.12 2015-12-09 03:01:07
2015-12-09 03:01:08     0.00 2015-12-09 03:01:08
2015-12-09 03:01:10    90.00 2015-12-09 03:01:10
2015-12-09 03:01:15    90.00 2015-12-09 03:01:15
2015-12-09 03:02:22   149.23 2015-12-09 03:02:22
2015-12-09 03:02:25     0.00 2015-12-09 03:02:25
2015-12-09 03:02:32   270.00 2015-12-09 03:02:32
2015-12-09 03:02:40      NaN 2015-12-09 03:02:40
2015-12-09 03:02:42    90.00 2015-12-09 03:02:42
2015-12-09 03:02:48   270.00 2015-12-09 03:02:48
2015-12-09 03:03:15     9.39 2015-12-09 03:03:15
2015-12-09 03:03:17   210.77 2015-12-09 03:03:17
2015-12-09 03:03:35   153.61 2015-12-09 03:03:35
2015-12-09 03:03:39    90.00 2015-12-09 03:03:39
2015-12-09 03:03:40   263.84 2015-12-09 03:03:40
2015-12-09 03:03:46   351.30 2015-12-09 03:03:46
2015-12-09 03:03:48   270.00 2015-12-09 03:03:48
2015-12-09 03:03:50   267.69 2015-12-09 03:03:50
2015-12-09 03:03:51   270.00 2015-12-09 03:03:51
2015-12-09 03:04:10   205.03 2015-12-09 03:04:10
2015-12-09 03:04:11    90.00 2015-12-09 03:04:11
2015-12-09 03:04:12   270.00 2015-12-09 03:04:12
2015-12-09 03:04:18      NaN 2015-12-09 03:04:18
2015-12-09 03:04:24     0.00 2015-12-09 03:04:24
```

Comment: With 2 min ago, to you mean exactly 120 sec ago?

Comment: @Stefan, I mean compare the heading value with one as close to 2 mins ago as possible doesn't have to be exactly 120 secs

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following (for 2 minutes differences):

```
def diff(ref):
    refvalue = ref['heading']
    selection = data.index - ref.name == np.timedelta64(2, 'm')
    values = data['heading'].loc[selection] - refvalue
    return values.mean()

data['diff'] = data.apply(diff, axis=1)
```

But this is not very efficient, because it does a O(n^2) comparison. For example, half of the entries could be skipped, because they are in the future.

I hope someone can suggest something better.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the `reindex` function, see

[Shifting row by delta time in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791565/shifting-row-by-delta-time-in-pandas/66025068#66025068)

and

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Maybe you want method='nearest'.