# Shifting row by delta time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                             Ask      Bid  AskVolume  BidVolume
Gmt time
2018-10-10 10:30:00.573  1.14908  1.14906       1.57       1.00
2018-10-10 10:30:01.044  1.14906  1.14904       1.00       6.67
2018-10-10 10:30:01.620  1.14905  1.14903       1.00       2.06
2018-10-10 10:30:01.934  1.14906  1.14902       1.95       4.69
2018-10-10 10:30:02.093  1.14904  1.14902       1.00       1.50
2018-10-10 10:30:02.422  1.14902  1.14901       1.20       1.25
2018-10-10 10:30:02.967  1.14902  1.14900       3.00       1.50
2018-10-10 10:30:03.485  1.14902  1.14899       1.50       6.75
2018-10-10 10:30:04.016  1.14902  1.14900       1.00       1.25
2018-10-10 10:30:04.584  1.14902  1.14899       1.10       3.94
2018-10-10 10:30:05.316  1.14902  1.14900       1.57       1.00
2018-10-10 10:30:06.457  1.14902  1.14899       1.10       3.00
2018-10-10 10:30:06.972  1.14901  1.14899       1.00       2.25
2018-10-10 10:30:07.606  1.14901  1.14898       2.70       3.00
2018-10-10 10:30:10.751  1.14901  1.14899       1.20       1.87
```

I want to shift `Ask` column by 1 second delta. I tried this, but returns NaN.

```
df = pd.read_csv('2hour.csv')
delta = pd.Timedelta(1,unit='s')
df['Gmt time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Gmt time'])
df.set_index(keys='Gmt time',inplace=True)
df['Shifted_Ask'] = df['Ask'].shift(freq=delta)
print df.head()
```

Expected:

```
Gmt time                 Ask      Bid           AskVolume  BidVolume   Shifted_Ask 
2018-10-10 10:30:00.573  1.14908  1.14906       1.57       1.00         1.14906          
2018-10-10 10:30:01.044  1.14906  1.14904       1.00       6.67         1.14902  
2018-10-10 10:30:01.620  1.14905  1.14903       1.00       2.06         1.14902 
2018-10-10 10:30:01.934  1.14906  1.14902       1.95       4.69         1.14902
2018-10-10 10:30:02.093  1.14904  1.14902       1.00       1.50         1.14902
```

Comment: Could you please post expected sample output with code tags in your post and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added the expected result. I just want the shifted `Ask` column by time. `Shifted_Ask` contains the `Ask` column by next second.

Comment: Could you please do let me know logic behind the new expected column here too?

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi - because the column ASK is not date time

Comment: @Backtrack But dataframe is indexed and sorted by time. How can I shift it by delta time?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 @RavinderSingh13 The new column, contains the `Ask` values for each second. Instead of shifting by index, I want to shift it by Index time. For example: we have 3 `Ask` rows for first second, I want to `Shifted_Ask` contains only one value of next second of `Ask` column. Shifting it by time.

Comment: You can shift the `Ask` by `delta_time` and then `reindex` it using `method=ffill`.

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani Would you mind explaining it in the code? Thank you.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi `df['Shifted_Ask'] = df.Ask.reindex(dd.index + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1), method='ffill').values`

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani It works!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @RishitSanmukhani for this very useful answer 2 years ago:

```
df['Shifted_Ask'] = df.Ask.reindex(dd.index + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1), method='ffill').values
```

Reference for reindex:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html